# Items Filtering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

Am trying to make a eCommorece project and I want to add filter dropmenues on the products table, to search from more than one database, but everytime I select an option I get this error below...

**https://flareapp.io/share/v5pzQz2P**

And here is the conde on the controller

```
$products = Product::orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->where( function($query) use($request){
            return $request->status_id ?
                $query->from('products')->where('status',$request->status_id) : '';})
        ->where( function($query) use($request){
            return $request->category_id ?
                $query->from('product_categories')->where('category_id',$request->category_id) : '';})
        ->paginate(30);
        
        $selected_id = [];
        $selected_id['status_id'] = $request->status_id;
        $selected_id['category_id'] = $request->category_id;

        return view('dashboard.products.index', compact('products', 'selected_id'), $data);
```

My blade view

```
form class="col-sm-5 px-2" action="{{ route('products.index') }}" method="GET">
                @csrf
                <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="status_id" aria-label="Bulk actions" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                  <option value="0" {{ $selected_id['status_id'] == '0' ? 'selected' : '' }}>All Products</option>
                  <option value="00" {{ $selected_id['status_id'] == '00' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Disabled Products</option>
                  <option value="1" {{ $selected_id['status_id'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Enabled Products</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form class="col-sm-5" action="{{ route('products.index') }}" method="GET">
                @csrf
                <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="category_id" aria-label="Bulk actions" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                  <option value="0" {{ $selected_id['category_id'] == '0' ? 'selected' : '' }}>All Products</option>
                  <option value="1" {{ $selected_id['category_id'] == '1' ? 'selected' : '' }}>11223123</option>
                </select>
              </form>
```

Comment: did you mean more than one table or database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      $products = Product::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                         ->categories()
                         ->when($request->status_id, function ($query, $request) {
                             return $query->from('products')->where('status', $request->status_id);
                         })
                         ->when($request->category_id, function ($query, $request) {
                             return $query->from('product_categories')->where('category_id', $request->category_id);
                         })
                         ->paginate(30);
```

Comment: It did not work it says "Attempt to read property "status_id" on string"

Error URL: https://flareapp.io/share/oPRbMrkP